# NServiceBus Tool - ReturnToSourceQueue Exits after Error

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

There are a few messages stuck in the error queue and I would like to transfer them back to the normal message queue so that NServiceBus Subscribers can pick them up and process them.

My colleague found the tool ReturnToSourceQueue.exe which helps you to transfer them on back to the queue. But when I try to run it on the Web server, where the subscribers are installed and the message queue is, ReturnToSourceQueue.exe gives me this message:

"ReturnToSourceQueue has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience"

Any clues as to how can I get around this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add the link to your image, we will integrate it.

Comment: Here's a guess, is the machine allowing outbound MSMQ and DTC traffic?  DTC is more likely the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we had to use the tool to move messages from error back to normal queue on a cluster, we experienced similar issues (on NServiceBus 2.5 as far as I remember). I found this [ReturnToSource powershell script](http://adamfyles.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/returntosourcequeue-powershell-script.html) that worked with a bit of tweaking. If it won't work out of the box, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finally got around by copying the whole downloaded folder of NServiceBus 3.2.8. It finds it's relevant dependencies that it needs to run and works absolutely like a dream. Sorted out 700+ messages from message queue.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a small tool for managing NServiceBus messages, it has been tested with remote servers, and provides Windows UI for selecting error messages.

You can download it [here](http://blog.halan.se/page/Service-Bus-MQ-Manager.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. Will download and install the windows interface. Looks quite good as well.